# Alipay/Wechat Pay payment from mobile website

Tags: payment-gateway, wechat, alipay

Is it possible from a mobile website to trigger a payment request in either:
1. Alipay
2. Wechat Pay

I'm specifically looking at the mainland China version of both if that makes a difference.

Answer (score 1):

If your website is based on WordPress (and possibly WooCommerce), you may want to have a look at a combination of [WP Wexin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-weixin/), [Woo WeChatPay](https://wordpress.org/plugins/woo-wechatpay/) and/or [WP Weixin Pay](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-weixin-pay/) (full disclosure: I am the developer).

For Alipay, there is no good working plugin I know of, unless you go through Stripe with [WooCommerce Stripe Payment Gateway](https://wordpress.org/plugins/payment-gateway-stripe-and-woocommerce-integration/)

Comment: It's a custom platform so unfortunately no wordpress... I was just wondering if it was possible at all.  I found something in Alipay and Wechat Pays Chinese documentation that looks like it will work but i'm not certain.   If WP Wexin can work with wechat pay then i'm guessing the answer for Wechat is yes!

Comment: You may be interested in the mini PHP SDK I included in the WordPress plugin, or for something bigger and more robust, EasyWechat by overtrue https://github.com/overtrue/wechat - at least to study the code and see how it's done